# How can a zsh script test whether it is being sourced?

Tags: zsh

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683279#answer-2687092) for a similar question for `bash` does not seem to work for `zsh`.  In fact, if I copy basically the same code given in that answer, to produce the script

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh -
# test.sh

[[ $_ != $0 ]] && echo "sourced\n" || echo "subshell\n"
```

the output hardly ever corresponds to the actual situation:

```
zsh% chmod +x ./test.sh
zsh% env -i /usr/bin/zsh -f
zsh% ./test.sh
sourced

zsh% /usr/bin/zsh ./test.sh
sourced

zsh% /bin/bash ./test.sh
sourced

zsh% source ./test.sh
subshell

zsh% . ./test.sh
subshell

zsh% env -i /bin/bash --norc --noprofile
bash-3.2$ ./test.sh
sourced

bash-3.2$ /usr/bin/zsh ./test.sh
sourced

bash-3.2$ /bin/bash ./test.sh
sourced

bash-3.2$ source ./test.sh
sourced

bash-3.2$ . ./test.sh
sourced
```

When the current interactive shell is `zsh`, the script gets it exactly wrong every time.  It fares a bit better under `bash` (though in a way reminiscent of the stopped watch that gets the time exactly right twice a day).

These truly *abysmal* results give me little confidence in this approach.

Is there something better?

Comment: If I were desperate I'd use `$SECONDS` - if it's zero, then it's a subshell; >0 and the file's been sourced. That idea is so stinky, I'm only posting it as a novelty item.

Answer (score 8):

```
if [[ $ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT == 'toplevel' ]]; then
    # We're not being sourced so run the colors command which in turn sources
    # this script and uses its content to produce representative output.
    colors
fi
```

Via Kurtis Rader [on the zsh-users mailing list](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2014/msg00812.html).

Comment: The variable is empty in both cases in my zsh 5.4.2.

Comment: Works in zsh 5.7.1, I use it to verify that the script is being sourced.

Comment: This does not work in Zsh 5.8.

Comment: Better to check whether 'file' is in zsh_eval_context. See `man zshparam` in zsh_eval_context where a dozen zsh_eval_contexts are described, all but one of which could be present in a non-sourced script, maybe nested with others. See answer by Marlon Richert above.

Answer (score 1):

To see if you're in a subshell, check the value of `$ZSH_SUBSHELL`:

```bash
if (( ZSH_SUBSHELL )); then
  echo "subshell, $ZSH_SUBSHELL fork(s) deep"
else
  echo "not a subshell"
fi
```

- `$ZSH_SUBSHELL` evaluates to `0` if , and only if, you’re not in a subshell. See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell

To see if you're being `source`d, check if `zsh_eval_context` contains the word `file`:

```bash
if (( zsh_eval_context[(I)file] )); then
  echo "sourced"
else
  echo "not sourced"
fi
```

- `$zsh_eval_context` will contain the word `file` when the code is being read directly from a file, such as when using the `.` or  `source` builtins. See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell
- `$zsh_eval_context[(I)file]`  evaluates to `0` if `$zsh_eval_context` does not contain the word `file`. See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts

Answer (score 0):

You could get the Shell Level:

```
[ $SHLVL -gt 1 ] && echo "subshell"
```

There's also (ZSH-only) `$ZSH_SUBSHELL`.

Obviously these break if you're nesting.

Comment: This does not help when you want to check if you're being `source`d.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't the answer you are looking for the difference between login and interactive shell?

```sh
localhost% cat foo
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

[[ $- == *i* ]] && print ' interactive=sourced' || print ' login=called'

localhost% source foo
 interactive=sourced
localhost% zsh foo   
 login=called
```